# How do you change the screen transition direction in kivy, within the python code?

Tags: python, kivy

I know how to change the transition direction in Kivy code form. Example:

```
Button:
    text: "Home" 
    size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
    on_release: 
        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        root.GoToMainWindow()
```

- However, I can not replicate this in python code.
- I want to be able to set the transition type in python code, as I am creating a set number of buttons in a for loop, in python
- Here are my two attempts:

```
GridButton = Button(text="More details", on_release=self.GoToMoreDetails, on_release=self.transition.direction("right"))
```

Or

```
GridButton = Button(text="More details", on_release=self.GoToMoreDetails, self.transition.direction("right"))
```

- The first attempt gives an error of 'keyword argument 'on_release' is repeated', to set the button press function.
- The second attempt gives in error "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the example how your app should look like "just for switching screens".

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class FirstPage(FloatLayout):

    def switch_screen(self):
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'SecondPage'

class SecondPage(FloatLayout):

    def switch_back(self):
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'FirstPage'

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.firstpage = FirstPage()
        screen = Screen(name='FirstPage')
        screen.add_widget(self.firstpage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.secondpage = SecondPage()
        screen = Screen(name='SecondPage')
        screen.add_widget(self.secondpage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

myapp = MyApp()
myapp.run()
```

`kivy` code:

```
FirstPage:

<FirstPage>:

    Button:
        text: "First"
        on_release: root.switch_screen()

<SecondPage>:

    Button:
        text: "Second"
        on_release: root.switch_back()
```

Comment: Thank you. To help anyone else looking for the answer, the specific line of code that I needed was "myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)"