# Question regarding changing screens in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm new to KIVYMD and have been trying to play around by creating a log in screen that transfers the user to a new page. I've gotten making the core of the screen down, like adding the textfields and buttons, but am not sure how I can implement a screen changing functionality to my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For reference here is my main code block:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from helpers import username_helper,password_helper
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton


class Demo_app(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette= "Pink"
        self.username= Builder.load_string(username_helper)
        screen.add_widget(self.username)
        self.password = Builder.load_string(password_helper)
        screen.add_widget(self.password)
        login = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Log In", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.4})
        screen.add_widget(login)
        signin = MDRectangleFlatButton(text="Sign Up", pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3})
        screen.add_widget(signin)
        return screen

Demo_app().run()
```

And here is my .kv file:

```
username_helper="""

MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Create/Enter your Username"
    helper_text:"Or click here if you forgot your Username"
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
    icon_right: "language-python"
    icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.6}
    size_hint_x:None 
    width:300

"""

password_helper="""
MDTextField:
    hint_text: "Create/Enter your Password"
    helper_text:"Or click here if you forgot your password "
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
    icon_right: "language-python"
    icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
    size_hint_x:None 
    width:300
"""
```

Comment: You should use `ScreenManager`. Most simple code is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085962/how-do-you-change-the-screen-transition-direction-in-kivy-within-the-python-cod/69087054#69087054).

Comment: I've toyed around with Screen Manager, but can't get it to function with a textfield

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to transfer those textinput data to a label in different class. I think this is what you need.(keep an eye on ids):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class FirstPage(FloatLayout):

    def switch_screen(self):
        secondpage = self.login_name = self.ids.login_name.text
        myapp.secondpage.update_name1(secondpage)
        secondpage = self.password_name = self.ids.password_name.text
        myapp.secondpage.update_name2(secondpage)
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'SecondPage'

class SecondPage(FloatLayout):

    def switch_back(self):
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='right', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'FirstPage'

    def update_name1(self, name_login):
        self.ids.name_login.text = (f'{name_login}:')

    def update_name2(self, name_password):
        self.ids.name_password.text = (f'{name_password}:')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.firstpage = FirstPage()
        screen = Screen(name='FirstPage')
        screen.add_widget(self.firstpage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.secondpage = SecondPage()
        screen = Screen(name='SecondPage')
        screen.add_widget(self.secondpage)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

myapp = MyApp()
myapp.run()
```

Here's `kivy` code:

```
FirstPage:

<FirstPage>:

    TextInput:
        id: login_name
        size_hint: .65, .08
        multiline: False
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .57}

    TextInput:
        id: password_name
        size_hint: .65, .08
        multiline: False
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .47}

    Button:
        text: "First"
        size_hint: .1, .1
        on_release: root.switch_screen()

<SecondPage>:

    Button:
        text: "Second"
        size_hint: .1, .1
        on_release: root.switch_back()

    Label:
        id: name_login
        text: "Login"
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .57}

    Label:
        id: name_password
        text: "Password"
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'x': .2, 'y': .47}
```